# Merge By Two Different Columns Disregarding the Order

Tags: r, join, merge, dplyr

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
df1: 

 COL1     COL2   VALUE
   A        B      1
   A        C      1
   A        F      1
   A        D      1 
   B        E      1

df2: 

ADV1     ADV2    VALUE2
  B        A       1
  A        C       1
  B        E       1
  D        A       1
```

The I want to disregard the order for COL1 and COL2 when I merge it with df1.

So as you can see COL1: A and COL2: B does not occur in df1 but those two values do exist in a Row...therefore we index match it. It is also important to keep the NA values in df1. I think it is a full join but the cache is that I want to disregard the order of COL1 and COL2 and the colnames are different.

```
  COL1     COL2   VALUE   VALUE2 
   A        B      1        1
   A        C      1        1
   A        F      1        NA
   A        D      1        1
   B        E      1        1
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear what the criteria for the merge/join in your case is. What do you mean by disregard order of values in columns? Why is there NA in the VALUE2 output column corresponding to A, F?

Comment: Thanks, just modified the description of the question @Gopala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to create a 'new' column that has the COL1/COL2 and ADV1/ADV2 united in a sorted order, and join based on that column using as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
df1$NEWCOL <- paste(pmin(df1$COL1, df1$COL2),
                    pmax(df1$COL1, df1$COL2),
                    sep = '')
df2$NEWCOL <- paste(pmin(df2$ADV1, df2$ADV2),
                    pmax(df2$ADV1, df2$ADV2),
                    sep = '')
df <- left_join(df1, df2)
```

Resulting output is as follows:

```
  COL1 COL2 VALUE NEWCOL ADV1 ADV2 VALUE2
1    A    B     1     AB    B    A      1
2    A    C     1     AC    A    C      1
3    A    F     1     AF <NA> <NA>     NA
4    A    D     1     AD    D    A      1
5    B    E     1     BE    B    E      1
```

Of course, you can remove unneeded columns as follows:

```
df <- select(df, COL1, COL2, VALUE, VALUE2)
```

Output as follows:

```
  COL1 COL2 VALUE VALUE2
1    A    B     1      1
2    A    C     1      1
3    A    F     1     NA
4    A    D     1      1
5    B    E     1      1
```

I am using `left_join` above given the input data. If there is a need to merge both sides, you can of course use `full_join` instead from the same `dplyr` package.

Comment: The first part: df1$NEWCOL didn't work. This is what happened when I executed it:                                                                                                Warning messages:
1: In Ops.factor(mmm, each) : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors
2: In Ops.factor(mmm, each) : ‘<’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: Yeah, you need to read the data with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`. Otherwise, it gets read as factors, and generally messes with things.

Comment: Do I just put that at the beginning of your answer?

Comment: No, in your code where you read the data or generated the data. For example: `df1 <- data.frame(COL1 = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B'), COL2 = c('B', 'C', 'F', 'D', 'E'), VALUE = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` OR if you used `read.csv` then wherever you are doing `df1 <- read.csv(......, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`.

Comment: Is that the only way to do it or can I change it in the middle of the code?

Comment: Sure...you can also do `df1$COL1 <- as.character(df1$COL1)` etc...for each of those four columns.